Does $x^TAx \approx 1$ imply $||A-xx^T||_2 \approx 0$, where $A$ positive definite and trace 1, $x$ is a unit vector?
Suppose $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $\text{tr}(A)=1$, $x$ is a unit vector. If $x^TAx=1-\delta$ where $\delta>0$ is a small number, can we give a upper bound for $||A-xx^T||_2^2=\text{tr }(A-xx^T)^2$ using $\delta$?
Since $\text{tr }(A-xx^T)^2=\text{tr}A^2-2(1-\delta)+1$, we need to show that tr$(A^2)$ is close to 1. Is it always true?

If the trace of $A$ equals $1$ then it'd eigenvalues add up to $1$. Maybe they are equal to $a,-a,1$ for some large $a$. In this case the trace of $A^2$ is not close to $1$.

@Leo $A$ is positive definite so $-a$ won't be its eigenvalue.

If the sum of the eigenvalues is 1, the sum of the squares will usually be much smaller.

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$ Since $\tr(A^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2$ and $\lambda_i>0$ we have, $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2=(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i)^2 - \sum_{i\neq j} \lambda_i \lambda_j<(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i)^2=1$.

@TedBlack Right, but we need to bound $|\sum\lambda_i^2-1|$ using $\delta$

It would be easier if you use the fact that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is similar to $(1-\delta)I$ (with $(1-\delta)n=1$).

Denote $\lambda_1$ as the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and we have $1\geq\lambda_1\geq1-\delta$ thus $\sum_i \lambda_i^2\geq (1-\delta)^2$, so $1-\text{tr}(A^2)\leq -\delta^2+2\delta$.
